# Points at which partial derivatives exist and are continuous

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given $ E = (xy : xy \neq 0 ) $ . Let $ f : \mathbb R^{2}\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined by 
$$f(x,y)=\cases{0,& if $xy=0$\\y\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+x\sin\left(\frac{1}{y}\right),& otherwise} .$$

Let $ S_1  $ be set of points in $ \mathbb R^{2}$  , where $f_x$ exists and $S_2 $ be set of points where $ f_y$ exists . Let $E_1$ be points where partial wrt x is continous and $E_2$ be set of points where $f_y$ is continous

I heed to determine what $S_i$ and $E_i$ are, $i=1,2 $

ATTEMPT : I calculated partial derivatives as

$f_x$ = $ -(y/x^{2}) \cos(1/x) + x\sin(1/y)$

$f_y = \sin1/x - (x/y^{2} )\cdot\cos (1/y) $

These both partials do not exist at X axis and Y axis and origin. At other points in xy plane they exist. Same for continuity. Is that enough, I'm not confident? Can anyone please elaborate? Thanks

Comment: To type fractions, use the forward slash like `p/q` for $p/q$ or use `\frac{p}{q}` for $\frac{p}{q}$.

Comment: for various values of $m,$ what happens on the lines $y = mx?$

Comment: @abel it ain't exist along that line .how do i proceed ?

Comment: what does not exist on the lines $y = mx?$

Comment: Both partials .

Answer (score 2):

let us look at $f_x.$ you have the formula $f_x = -\dfrac{y}{x^2}\cos(1/x) + \sin(1/y)$

it is clear that $f_x$ is continuous everywhere except possibly on the $x$ and $y$ axis. we will look at the axes in turn.

on the $x$-axis, $f$ is identically zero. so $f_x(x, 0) = 0$ for all $x.$

on the $y$-axis, we will use the definition of $f_x$ to compute $f_x.$

for 
$y \neq 0, f_x(0,y) = \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(h, y)}{h}
=\dfrac{y \sin (1/h) + h\sin (1/y)}{h} = \sin(1/y)+ y\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{\sin (1/h)}{h}$ does not exist.

so the set $S_1 = \{(0,y) \colon y \neq 0 \}$

can you do the rest?

Comment: Why is partial wrt x is identically zero in x axis

Comment: is not $f(x, 0) = 0$ for all $x?$

Comment: In f_x i have calculated we cannot put y=o

Comment: @SophieClad Use the definition of partial derivative.

Comment: @GitGud but when doing it without definition should not produce same results ?

Comment: @tomb_raider When you get an expression for the partial derivative, you're implicitly using the definition. The rules you use to compute derivatives were all once proved using the definition. There's no reason why derivatives at different points should be given by the same expression.

Comment: @GitGud still donot understand where is error in computation of sophie clad's work .there is confusion whether it does not exist at x axis and y axis or only at y axis ?

Comment: @GitGud could you throw a bit more light on why different computations for same question give different result ?

Comment: @tomb_raider What does not exist? There are two partial derivatives, I don't know which you're talking about. Sophie wrote $f_x=-(y/x^{2}) \cos(1/x) + x\sin(1/y)$. This doesn't make sense, correct would be $f_x\color{red}{(x,y)}=-(y/x^{2}) \cos(1/x) + x\sin(1/y)$, but now it's necessary to specify what $(x,y)$ is. As it turns out this equality is only valid for $(x,y)$ with $y\neq 0$. So for $(x,0)$ with any $x$, you need to use the definition. The expression she wrote is right only if $(x,y)\neq (x,0)$. Does this help?

Comment: @GitGud my question is the expression for$ f_x $ is not valid for y=0 but also for x=0 and both .so why use definition?as per she wrote doesn't that cover whole of x and y axis

Comment: @tomb_raider I made a mistake, I meant to say "this equality is only valid for $(x,y)$ such that $x\neq 0\land y\neq 0$".

Comment: @GitGud this is exactly what she wrote but abel's answer saying something different?

Comment: @tomb_raider No, Sophie proceeded with saying that the partials don't exist at the axis, this isn't true as abel as shown.

Comment: @GitGud but say if someone is not using definition , then how to see from what sophie has computed ? Because from expression it seems like that ?

Comment: @tomb_raider You can't see it just from the expression. You need to look at $f$'s definition. It's defined by cases and so you have to deal with it by cases. In one of the cases you're using the definition implicitly, in the other you need to use it explicitly.